# Axis2 Client - Parsing results with href

Tags: java, soap, client, apache-axis, href

I am working on a Web Services client with auto-generated Axis2 code using XMLBeans.  Sending the request works as expected, but I am unable to successfully parse the response.  The issue is that the response data is not contained within the elements that Axis2 is looking for.  Axis2 is looking for the results in a `SendAndCommitResponse` element, which in turn contains a single element with an href to the `TransactionResult` element.

For reference, the original WSDL is [here](https://api.demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/transaction/v11/wsdl).

The structure of the return SOAP Envelope is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://secure2.e-xact.com/vplug-in/transaction/rpc-enc/" xmlns:types="http://secure2.e-xact.com/vplug-in/transaction/rpc-enc/encodedTypes">
  <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <q1:SendAndCommitResponse xmlns:q1="http://secure2.e-xact.com/vplug-in/transaction/rpc-enc/Response">
      <SendAndCommitResult href="#id1"/>
    </q1:SendAndCommitResponse>
    <types:TransactionResult xsi:type="types:TransactionResult" id="id1">

    </types:TransactionResult>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The results I am trying to parse will be within the `TransactionResult` tag, but Axis2 is looking for the tags within the `SendAndCommitResponse`.

My question would be, is there a way to tell the Axis2 client, when parsing the results, to follow the href to the correct elemental for the result data?  If not, could I manually modify the generated client code to look at `TransactionResult` directly?

Answer (score 2):

Your web service might be written on Axis1. You could use Axis1 to generate your client. I had a same kind of issue and got corrected using Axis1